# Spring cloud kafka and avro serialization issue

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, avro, spring-cloud-stream

I use `spring-cloud-stream-schema` to read avro messages from kafka. I configured input channel in `MessagesChannels`:

```
@Input("topicName1")
SubscribableChannel fromInput1();
```

I have configuration file like that:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBinding(MessagesChannels.class)
@EnableSchemaRegistryClient
public class MessageConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public MessageConverter topic1MessageConverter() throws IOException {
    return new AvroSchemaMessageConverter(MimeType.valueOf("avro/bytes"));
  }
}
```

And my consumer is called with

```
fromInput1().subscribe(this::onMessage);

void onMessage(Message message) {
}
```

When I actually sent message I got this error:

```
nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: 
org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to [B
```

Actually raw bytes are parsed correctly into `org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record`. But spring requires `Message` class. How to cast `GenericData$Record` to `Message` or how to cast `GenericData$Record` directly to generated by avro-tools class?

More details:

```
2017-03-06 11:23:10.695 ERROR 19690 --- [afka-listener-1] o.s.kafka.listener.LoggingErrorHandler   : Error while processing: ConsumerRecord(topic = topic1, partition = 0, offset = 7979, CreateTime = 1488784987569, checksum = 623709057, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 36, key = null, value = {"foor": "bar"})

org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$ReceivingHandler@4bf9d802]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to [B
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:139)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.FixedSubscriberChannel.send(FixedSubscriberChannel.java:70)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.FixedSubscriberChannel.send(FixedSubscriberChannel.java:64)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set the `contentType` for the incoming message channel to use `application/*+avro` as specified [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Brooklyn.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_avro_schema_registry_client_message_converters)